# Solving Math Limits Questions with Square Roots

Tags: limits

I seek your help on this question.

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{9x^6+7x^3+5x}-\sqrt{9x^6+6x^2+3x}\right)$$

This is what I have done so far.

[image: Workings]

I tried to divide both numerator and denominator with the largest power but I am not too sure if I am doing it right. Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Please use MathJax to enter the question and answer here.

Comment: Hi, welcome! Generally on MSE people will expect that these math steps are written out in MathJax. If you edit the question to write this out in MathJax, people will probably be more receptive to the post. I will look over your pictures and attempt an answer :)

Comment: Steps 1-3 look correct, but check the numerator in the last step and make sure you reduced the fraction in the numerator correctly.

Comment: In fact, check your denominator on the last step as well.

Comment: In the third step, divide by $x^3$ both numerator and denominator. Make sure to distribute properly.

Comment: Thank you guys! I managed to solve the question! Thank you ! :D

Comment: A brief introduction to posting math notation is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that, by asymptotic relations:
$$(1+f(x))^{\alpha} \;\; \sim \;\; \alpha \cdot f(x) \;\; \text{when}\;\; f(x) \to 0$$
One can write:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{9x^6+7x^3+5x}-\sqrt{9x^6+6x^2+3x}\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{9x^6+6x^2+3x}\cdot\left(\sqrt{\frac{9x^6+7x^3+5x}{9x^6+6x^2+3x}}-1\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{9x^6+6x^2+3x}\cdot\left(\sqrt{\frac{9x^6+6x^2+3x+(7x^3-6x^2)}{9x^6+6x^2+3x}}-1\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{9x^6+6x^2+3x}\cdot\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{7x^3-6x^2}{9x^6+6x^2+3x}}-1\right)\;\; \sim\;\;\lim_{x\to\infty}3x^3\cdot\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{7x^3}{9x^6}}-1\right)\;\; \lim_{x\to\infty}3x^3\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{7}{9x^3}=\frac{7}{6}$$

So, the limit is $\frac{7}{6}$.